# Comprobar typeof de un input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo el siguiente problema:

He creado el siguiente input de text en html

```
   <label for="varSpeed">PlayerSpeed</label>
   <input type="text" id="varSpeed">
   <input type="button" onclick="updateSpeed()" value="Update">
```

El valor esperado es un número, y almaceno ese valor puesto en el input de text en la siguiente variable

```
function updateSpeed(){
    movementQuotient = parseInt(document.getElementById('varSpeed').value)
}
```

Hago el parseInt ya que lo que ponga en el input text es por defecto una string.
Entonces lo que quiero hacer es una comprobación que haga lo siguiente

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById('varSpeed').value) == numero){
      movementQuotient = parseInt(document.getElementById('varSpeed').value)
}else{
        console.log("introduzca un caracter valido")
}
```

Pero no se como comprobar si document.getElementById('varSpeed').value es un número o no, ya que al hacer parseInt de una string que no contiene solo un número se me complica todo y no encuentro forma de solucionarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola para eso puedes utilizar la función core isNaN que retorna verdadero si una expresión NO es un número.

```
if (!isNaN(document.getElementById('varSpeed').value)) {
  movementQuotient = parseInt(document.getElementById('varSpeed').value)
} else {
  console.log("introduzca un caracter valido")
}
```